Let $G$ be a k-regular graph on at least $3$ vertices. Then $G$ or $G$ has a Hamiltonian path.
I want to show that for a $k$-regular graph $G$, i.e., every vertex has degree $k$, on at least $3$ vertices, $G$ or $\overline{G}$ has a Hamiltonian path.
There have been some related posts, e.g.,
here.
Most of the proofs I have seen separate the proof into two cases where $|V(G)|$ is even and odd.
However, I was wondering why such separation in cases is needed.
I assumed one can directly prove the stronger statement that $G$ or $\overline{G}$ has a Hamiltonian cycle by Dirac's theorem (see below in answers).
Any insights or validation is appreciated.

If $k \geq \frac{n}{2}$, then $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle by Dirac's theorem.
Assume now $k \leq \frac{n}{2}-1$. Note that $\overline{G}$ is $(n-k-1)$-regular. Thus $\forall v \in V(\overline{G})$:
\begin{align}
d(v) \geq n - (\frac{n}{2}-1) - 1 = \frac{n}{2}
\end{align}
Again by Dirac's theorem, $\overline{G}$ has a Hamiltonian cycle.
